# How do I reinstall Linux grub without using boot-installer?

Tags: grub2, 20.04, uefi

Good evening,

I got the problem that Linux grub does not start. It seems my computer can't find a bootable OS in Legacy-Mode (where Linux is installed) anymore. When I start the computer on legacy mode, I just get a black screen and nothing happens. Windows (running in uefi) still works fine.

**How can I "tell" my computer to automatically start Linux again when selecting Legacy mode without affecting my Windows on Uefi-Mode? How do I reinstall Linux grub without using boot-installer?**

My setup:

- DELL Laptop running in dual boot windows 10 + ubuntu 20.04.
  Windows is running in UEFI and Ubuntu in Legacy
- I recently updated my ubuntu version from 18.04 to 20.4 and also extended the partitions size from 10 to 30 gb (using Live-Stick and gparted).
- Also I used dconf-editor to set the dock panel to the center. After all this changes still everything worked fine for some days.

What I tried:

- force grub to start with SHIFT, but then only a "GRUB"-text appears below the text of the black screen and still nothing happens.
- start Linux on a LIVE-USB and try to reinstall grub with the boot-installer, but I got the error "The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session...".
- I also tried to reinstall grub manually following a guide (mount folders of the partition and then update-grub etc.). Nothing worked.

Comment: Is there some reason to have Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode on UEFI system? Boot-Repair will see UEFI Windows on gpt drive and want to install the UEFI version of grub as that is what just about everyone wants. Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. Normal reinstall of BIOS grub should be mount / & /boot (if separate) and install grub. Old but still should be valid for BIOS grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal You do have bios_grub partition as gpt requires that for correct install of grub-pc on gpt drives.

Comment: Hello Olfred, thank you a lot for your help! I will try again and post the summary report from Boot-Repair. The reason I installed Ubuntu in Legacy and not in UEFI, is that I had no idea about Dual boot systems and for some reason it didn't work on UEFI, so I just put it on Legacy.

Comment: Then I would boot live installer in UEFI boot mode, add Boot-Repair with ppa and have it run the full re-install of grub, replacing grub-pc for BIOS with grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI boot. Then both Windows & Ubuntu will be in UEFI boot mode. And if Windows fast start up is off, you can dual boot from grub menu.

Comment: And only by installing grub in uefi, my whole whole partition will move from legacy to UEFI? And is there a risk I will destroy any windows boot file?

Comment: Something very strange just happened. I wanted to boot ubuntu from my USB-Stick (as I did several times today) to get the boot-repair summary report and as I selected "boot from USB" suddenly my Ubuntu partition started with login and everything. I guess I really need to move over to uefi, something is going terribly wrong here

Comment: So when I start the repair tool in uefi, I dont get the option to "repair as recommended". I only get the option to show to you the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dKj2Vqk3G9/

Comment: If I run it in Legacy mode: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yYrVPVdjYB/

Comment: Your UEFI report does not show NVMe drive, but BIOS does? And BIOS version wants to install the UEFI verison of grub. Many have had to update both UEFI and NVMe firmware. That may be part of issue. And reinstall of grub would not be sdX, but nvme0n1. And grub does not like to install to gpt partitioned drives in BIOS mode unless you have a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with bios_grub partition. You already have ESP on the NVMe drive.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot have a mix of UEFI and legacy. You can have both UEFI or both legacy but not a mix of both. Please see snippet from [Ubuntu documentation here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI):
[image]

Comment: Only because he has two drives does it work. But always better to have Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows if dual booting. And just about always better to have gpt partitioning. The only time for MBR(msdos), is if a drive has to have a BIOS boot version of Windows on that drive. Other drives can be gpt even with most very old systems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. Neither boot-repair nor installing manually with sudo grub-install /dev/sdX helped me out to reinstall grub. I only went from one to another error. On https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Reparatur/ I found the command for Legacy/Bios mode: "sudo apt-get --reinstall install grub-common grub-pc os-prober # grub-gfxpayload-lists" and now everythink works fine again.

Thank you everyone for trying to help me!